# How to save session data in alexa skill without using session attributes?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

In my skill I read an RSS feed and I want to reuse the data readed in current session but I can't use SessionAttributes because the object is bigger than [8000 char](https://developer.amazon.com/it-IT/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-format).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use persistent attributes, it'll basically store the data in DynamoDB and the data will be available between the sessions too.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/manage-attributes.html#persistent-attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS Lambda for your backend then, you can save your data in a global variable for the session. Otherwise uses Dynamo Db.

Comment: The global variable are shared between users?

Comment: If you don't want to share data between users then make a global dictionary which will keep the data like sessionData = {"userID": data}. In this way you will have separate data for every user.